# What is "T..." on Java?

Tags: java, generics, syntax, libgdx

Looking at the methods of [the Array class on libgdx](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/Array.java). I found this method:

```
public void addAll (T... array) {
    addAll(array, 0, array.length);
}
```

I had never seen that "T..." before, and it turns out that it's incredibly hard to search for "T..." either on Google or here on Stack Overflow. I think I understand generics, but the "..." is new to me.

What does that mean? So, for example, if T is String, then how would I use this method? Why would I use it? And how would that be different from using "T[]" instead?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `T...` is just a [varargs parameter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html), where the element type happens to be `T`, the generic type parameter of the class.

The point is that you can call the method like this (assuming `array` is an `Array<String>`):

```
array.addAll("x", "y", "z");
```

which will be equivalent to

```
array.addAll(new String[] { "x", "y", "z" });
```

This can be used without generics too. For example:

```
public static int sum(int... elements) {
    int total = 0;
    for (int element : elements) {
        total += element;
    }
    return total;
}
```

Varargs parameters were introduced in Java 5.

Comment: T is part of generics though, although in this case, it's used with varargs.

Comment: @SnakeDoc: Yes, but I think it's the varargs bit that the OP didn't understand.

Comment: ah, I see. maybe a link to generics just for completeness?

Comment: @SnakeDoc: Have noted that it's a generic type parameter, but if you read the question he talks about "if T is String" which suggests an understanding of generics, and it's also tagged "generics".

Answer (score 7):

There are two unrelated things here:

**Firstly**, this is probably a class which uses [Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics), so the `T` is a parametrized type.

**Secondly**, the `T...` parameter declaration is a [varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html)